# Django related objects are missing from celery task (race condition?)

Tags: python, django, celery, race-condition

Strange behavior, that I don't know how to explain. I've got a model, `Track`, with some related `points`. I call a celery task to performs some calculations with points, and they seem to be perfectly reachable in the method itself, but unavailable in celery task.

```py
@shared_task
def my_task(track):
    print 'in the task', track.id, track.points.all().count()

def some_method():
    t = Track()
    t.save()
    t = fill_with_points(t)  # creating points, attaching them to a Track
    t.save()
    print 'before the task', track.id, track.points.all().count()
    my_task.delay(t)
```

That prints the following:

```
before the task, 21346, 2971
in the task, 21346, 0
```

Strange thing though, when I put a time.sleep(10) at the first line of `my_task` or before calling `my_task` at all, it works out well, like there's some race condition. But the first printed line clearly says that `points` are available in the database, when it makes a select query (`track.points.all().count()`).

Comment: What is the context `some_method` is being called in? Is it from a view, or a management command, or what?

Comment: It's other model's `save` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've solved it using [django-transaction-hooks](http://django-transaction-hooks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It still looks kinda scary to replace my DB backend, but `django-celery-transactions` seems to be broken in Django 1.6. Now my setup looks like this:

settings.py:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'transaction_hooks.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'foo',
        },
    }
SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {'default':'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2'}  # this is required, or South breaks
```

models.py:

```py
from django.db import connection

@shared_task
def my_task(track):
    print 'in the task', track.id, track.points.all().count()

def some_method():
    t = Track()
    t.save()
    t = fill_with_points(t)  # creating points, attaching them to a Track
    t.save()
    print 'before the task', track.id, track.points.all().count()
    connection.on_commit(lambda: my_task.delay(t))
```

Results:

```
before the task, 21346, 2971
in the task, 21346, 2971
```

It still seems strange that such a common use case has no native celery or Django solution.

Comment: For anyone reading this: as of django 1.9, django-transaction-hooks has been merged into Django trunk, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit and http://django-transaction-hooks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#prerequisites

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume this is due to transaction isolation.

Django transactions by default are tied to requests; and while a transaction is active, no other process will see the changes until the transaction is committed. If you're in the middle of a save method, and there are quite a lot of other actions that take place before the request finishes, it seems likely that Celery starts processing the task before the transaction is committed. You could fix this by committing manually or by delaying the task.

Comment: How do I actually do that? `transaction.atomic()` doesn't help (see the above). I've tried to move all the `some_method` code from `save` method to `post_save` signal to prevent any transaction isolation issues (that should do it, right?), but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Ok, so that's *clearly* a transaction issue and the same case is well-described in the Celery docs (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#database-transactions). The problem now is, how do I trigger a manual commit inside a `post_save` signal? The signal itself runs inside an atomic block and throws an exceptions for any attempt of `transaction.commit()` or `with transaction.commit_manually()`. I also found this ticket, which is relevant, but apparently in wontfix state: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14051

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER pass model objects to celery tasks. This is because the session might expire (or be different) in the celery task compared to your Django application and this object will not be linked to the session and thus may not be available/beheave badly. What you should do is send the id. So something like `track_id` and then get the object from the database by issuing a query. That should most likely solve your problem.

```
@shared_task
def my_task(track_id):
    track = Track.query.get(track_id)  # Or how ever the query should be
    print 'in the task', track.id, track.points.all().count()

def some_method():
    t = Track()
    t.save()
    t = fill_with_points(t)  # creating points, attaching them to a Track
    t.save()
    print 'before the task', track.id, track.points.all().count()
    my_task.delay(t.id)  # Pass the id here, not the object
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Instead I've got `Exception: Track matching query does not exist.` when trying to get it by id in the task method. It's perfectly available out of the task scope, in `some_method`, though.

Comment: Where is `some_method` being called from?

Comment: Scope has nothing to do with it.  The object you updated is in an entirely different runtime object (wsgi/appserver vs. celeryd).

Comment: It's called from other model's `save` method. The model is something called `UserUpload`, and contains a temporarily file with points I fill my track with.

Comment: Does the call `t.save` commit to database? As I understand the only way this would work is if it commits (because in `my_task` the session is different). Try adding a `session.commit()` before you call the celery task and call the celery task with `t.id`

Comment: I guess it should - I never switched autocommit off. What's `session`? I tried to make a `transaction.atomic()` block, then run `my_task.delay` - still no help.