# django DoesNotExist matching query does not exist with postgres only

Tags: python, django, postgresql, exception, celery

The `assets` django app I'm working on runs well with SQLite but I am facing performance issues with deletes / updates of large sets of records and so I am making the transition to a PostgreSQL database.

To do so, I am starting fresh by updating `theapp/settings.py` to configure PostgreSQL, starting with a fresh db and deleting the `assets/migrations/` directory. I am then running:

```
./manage.py makemigrations assets
./manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
./manage.py createsuperuser
```

I have a function called within a registered `post_create` signal. It runs a scan when a `Scan` object is created. Within the class `assets.models.Scan`:

```
@classmethod
def post_create(cls, sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        return

    from celery.result import AsyncResult
    # get the domains for the project, from scan
    print("debug: task = tasks.populate_endpoints.delay({})".format(instance.pk))
    task = tasks.populate_endpoints.delay(instance.pk)
```

The offending code:

```
from celery import shared_task
....
import datetime

@shared_task
def populate_endpoints(scan_pk):
    from .models import Scan, Project, 
    from anotherapp.plugins.sensual import subdomains

    scan = Scan.objects.get(pk=scan_pk) #<<<<<<<< django no like
    new_entries_count = 0
    project = Project.objects.get(id=scan.project.id)
    ....
```

The resultant exception `DoesNotExist` raised:

```
debug: task = tasks.populate_endpoints.delay(2)
     [2017-09-14 23:18:34,950: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task assets.tasks.populate_endpoints[4555d329-2873-4184-be60-55e44c46a858] raised unexpected: DoesNotExist('Scan matching query does not exist.',)
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
         R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
         return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/src/app/theapp/assets/tasks.py", line 12, in populate_endpoints
    scan = Scan.objects.get(pk=scan_pk)
```

Interacting through `./manage.py shell` however indicates that `Scan` object with pk == 2 exists:

```
>>> from assets.models import Scan
>>> Scan.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Scan: ACME Web Test Scan>]>
>>> s = Scan.objects.all().first()
>>> s.pk
2
```

My only guess is that at the time the `post_create` function is called, the `Scan` object still does not exist in the PostgreSQL database, despite `save()` having been called.
SQLite does not exhibit this problem.
Also, I haven't found a relevant, related problem on stackoverflow as the `DoesNotExist` exception looks to be fairly generic and caused by many things. 
Any ideas on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do both pks have the same type? You have not provided the model spec. If you are not declaring it explicitly, it should be ints. But not sure whether this could be something of an issue when migrating from one db to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [well known problem](https://www.hypertrack.com/blog/2016/10/08/dealing-with-database-transactions-in-django-celery/) resulting from transactions and isolation level - sometimes the transaction has not been commited when the task is executed and if your isolation level is READ COMMITED then you can't indeed read this record from another process. [Django 1.9 introduced the `on_commit` hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) as a solution.

NB : technically this question is a duplicate of [Django related objects are missing from celery task (race condition?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862942) but the accepted answer uses `django-transaction-hooks` which has since then been merged into django.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I adapted the `TransactionAwareTask` class snippet in the first link successfully.